# Netlogo Cyle using turtle_index

Tags: cycle

I am using a turtle_index code to create a cycle in Netlogo. The cycle works but it is only using one turtle at a time. Each turtle completes the cycle before the next turtle starts the cycle. I would like all turtles to involved in the cycle at the same time. Is there a faster way to make this happen than using:

```
to go  
  ask turtle 1 [cycle-forward] 
  wait 0.5 
  ask turtle 2 [cycle-forward] 
  wait 0.5 
  ask turtle 3[cycle-forward] 
end
```

Comment: `Wait` is a primitive that stops all agents, not just the currently acting turtle. As I understand your example above, turtle 1 cycles forward, then the whole simulation waits half a second, then turtle 2 cycles forward, simulation waits, etc. I'm not sure that actually accomplishes what you hope to. Since Netlogo agents perform discrete actions one at a time, you may instead need to rework your `cycle-forward` procedure such that all your turtles perform each individual step within that procedure.

Comment: I have a cycle set up using globals [turtle_index] and a turtle counter so that the turtles will go through the cycle one at a time. What I want is for the one the turtles to go through the cycle in a line so that each turtle is at a different point in the cycle. Right now, one turtle goes through the entire cycle before the next turtle goes through the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Okay from your comment I think I understand. One way to tackle this is to have `turtles-own` variables such that turtles know what step they have done and whether they have acted on the current tick. That way, they won't do a step out of turn. You can then break your cycle down into steps and use logical operators so that turtles don't take a step if they do not fulfill some criteria that you set. For example:

```
turtles-own [
  step1?
  step2?
  step3?
  acted?
]
to setup

  ca
  reset-ticks
  crt 10 [
    set step1? false
    set step2? false
    set step3? false
    set acted? false    
  ]

end

to go
  ask turtles [
    set acted? false
  ]
  cycle
  tick

end

to cycle
  let step1t one-of turtles with [ step1? = false ]
  if step1t != nobody [
    ask step1t [
      set step1? true
      set acted? true
      ;;; example step 1
      set color red
      set heading 45
      fd 3
    ]    
  ]

  let step2t one-of turtles with [step1? = true and step2? = false and acted? = false]
  if step2t != nobody [
    ask step2t [
      set step2? true
      set acted? true
      ;;; example step 2
      set size 1.5
      set heading 90
      fd 3
    ]
  ]

  let step3t one-of turtles with [step2? = true and step3? = false and acted? = false]
  if step3t != nobody [
    ask step3t [
      set step3? true
      set acted? true
      ;;; example step 3
      set color color + 2
      set heading 135
      fd 3
    ]
  ] 
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!